# TextInputLayout not animating when OnFocusChangeListener applied to wrapped EditText

Tags: java, android

Can't say it much more clearly than in the title.  I have an EditText wrapped by a Text Input Layout.  I'm trying to trigger an event when that EditText loses focus.  However, once the event listener is applied, the TextInputLayout no longer animates the text, it just sits on the editText line until information is entered, at which time it does animate.  Can anyone give me some insight as to why this is happening?

Edit: Layout file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/card_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="11dp"
        android:text="The fields below will be used to calculate your training maxes.  Please enter your best rep record, or 1RM, for each lift.  Training maxes will be determined using the following formula provided in Beyond 5/3/1: \n(Weight Lifted x Reps X .0333 + Weight Lifted)" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/squat_container"
        style="@style/linear_layout_style">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/squatWeight_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Squat Weight" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtInputLayoutSquat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/squatReps_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Repetitons" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bench_container"
        style="@style/linear_layout_style">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bechpressWeight_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Bench Press Weight" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/benchpressReps_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Repetitons" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/deadlift_container"
        style="@style/linear_layout_style">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/deadliftWeight_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Deadlift Weight" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/deadliftReps_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Repetitons" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ohp_container"
        style="@style/linear_layout_style">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ohpWeight_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Overhead Press Weight" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ohpReps_editText"
                style="@style/editText_floating_label"
                android:hint="Repetitons" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When focus is away from `EditText` wrapped in `TextInputLayout`, it will animate. So, whether is there only one focus on `EditText` in the full screen or not? If not, try to add another focusable `View` and then see.

Comment: The stuff I have inside the listener is working when focus is lost, but when you click into the text box, the hint doesn't "float"

Comment: Could you post your layout file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to deal with the same issue.

The workaround I used was using a custom EditText and adding a custom listener to it to be called when the onFocusChanged method is fired.

**Custom EditText**  (Boiler plate code is not shown)

```
public class EditTextPlus extends AppCompatEditText {
    //This is the custom listener you will use
    public OnFocusChangeListener customListener;

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (customListener != null) {
            customListener.onFocusChange(this, focused);
        }
    }
}
```

**In Activity/Fragment**

```
yourEditText.customListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        //Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Don't forget to use the custom EditText in the xml as well and not the default EditText.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry I haven't responded, but this looks like a good solution.  In my case, it seems that a third party library was the culprit.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Qumbaala I'm glad you worked things out. Anyway I hope this post could help others having this issue.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't solve the issue but does give some insight (I'll update if I figure out a solution), but seems like the animated hint is dependent on `OnFocusChangedListener`, which gets overwritten when you add your own listener.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175344

**EDIT:**

Per https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178693...

We're now using a different way to determine if the `EditText` is focused. For now do something like:

```
TextInputLayout inputLayout = ...;
EditText editText = inputLayout.getEditText();
final OnFocusChangeListener existing = editText.getOnFocusChangeListener();

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
        existing.onFocusChange(view, focused);
        // Your custom logic
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I looked at the binaries and suspected it was something like that. My temporary solution was to programmatically add something to the edittext once it gained focus, but this is better.