# OnFocusChanged in TextInputLayout is causing issues in Hint Label floating

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, onfocuschangelistener

**What I am doing**

I am validating user input in `onFocusChanged`

**My problem**

My custom `onFocusChanged` disturbed the default `onFocusChanged` of `TextInputEditText` and because of that the hint label that floats up doesn't comes back to the `TextInputEditText` when I focus on other `TextInputEditText`

**What I did**
I found work around for that [TextInputLayout not animation hint label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197312/textinputlayout-not-animating-when-onfocuschangelistener-applied-to-wrapped-edit) . This is working for many people but not for me .

Code :

```
etCurrentPswd.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(etCurrentPswd));
        etNewPswd.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(etNewPswd));
        etConfirmPswd.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(etConfirmPswd));

        etCurrentPswd.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        etNewPswd.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        etConfirmPswd.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

 // handling focus change
        final View.OnFocusChangeListener etCurrentPswdFC = tiCurrentPassword.getEditText().getOnFocusChangeListener();
        final View.OnFocusChangeListener etNewPswdFC = tiNewPassword.getEditText().getOnFocusChangeListener();
        final View.OnFocusChangeListener etConfirmPswdFC = tiConfirmPassword.getEditText().getOnFocusChangeListener();

        etCurrentPswd.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
                if (!focused) {
                    etCurrentPswdFC.onFocusChange(view, focused);
                    mPresenter.checkCurrentPassword(etCurrentPswd.getText().toString(), etNewPswd.getText().toString(), etConfirmPswd.getText().toString(), false);
                }

            }
        });

        etNewPswd.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
                if (!focused) {
                    etNewPswdFC.onFocusChange(view, focused);
                    mPresenter.checkNewPassword(etCurrentPswd.getText().toString(), etNewPswd.getText().toString(), etConfirmPswd.getText().toString(), false);
                }

            }
        });

        etConfirmPswd.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focused) {
                if (!focused) {
                    etConfirmPswdFC.onFocusChange(view, focused);
                    mPresenter.checkConfirmPassword(etCurrentPswd.getText().toString(), etNewPswd.getText().toString(), etConfirmPswd.getText().toString(), false);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: the code provided is a bit unclear, what are `Pswd`s? Are those `EditText`s, or `TextInputLayout`s?

Comment: et stands for EditText and ti stands for TextInputLayouts.

Comment: thank you, must've been blind by then, still the order is a bit odd ;)